# Почему pytest не видит модуль, хотя он установлен

Tags: python, aiohttp

В моем проекте используется aiohttp, python3.9. Еще вчера и при запуске программы, и при тестировании pycharm видел aiohttp. Но теперь почему-то pycharm почему-то не видит aiohttp. Я пробовал запускать прогу и тестировать со всех интерпретаторов, которые у меня есть в pycharm. Но pycharm все равно не видит aiohttp (Module Not Found Error). Причем я посмотрел установленные пакеты в одном из интерпретаторов - aiohttp есть. Помогите пожалуйста, в чем может проблема?

Тестировал на pytest

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если у вас в Pycharm создано виртуальное окружение для проекта, то в нем скорее всего не будут видны установленные глобально модули. Нужно или в настройках проекта выбрать глобальный интерпретатор вместо виртуального окружения, или в само виртуальное окружение установить модуль.